# Mapper output.collect()?

Tags: mapreduce

The mapper invokes this two times.

```
out.collect(new Text("Car"),new Text("Subaru");
out.collect(new Text("Cr-v"),new Text("Honda");
```

Does the `reduce()` also get called two times ?

Comment: Can you give more context? I assume you're talking about a Hadoop job, but with no details it's hard to get an idea what you are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume you're talking about `OutputCollector.collect(K,V)?`

`reduce()` gets called once for each [key, (list of values)] pair. To explain, let's say you called:

```
out.collect(new Text("Car"),new Text("Subaru");
out.collect(new Text("Car"),new Text("Honda");
out.collect(new Text("Car"),new Text("Ford");
out.collect(new Text("Truck"),new Text("Dodge");
out.collect(new Text("Truck"),new Text("Chevy");
```

Then `reduce()` would be called twice with the pairs

```
reduce(Car, <Subaru, Honda, Ford>)
reduce(Truck, <Dodge, Chevy>)
```

So in your example, yes, the function `reduce()` would be called twice. I hope that helps.